# How to type arrows for restriction and induction of representation?

Tags: math-mode, arrows

I'm writing an article for representation theory and I want to type downward arrow for restriction and upward arrow for induction. The `$\downarrow$` and `$\uparrow$` give arrows that aren't right next to the letters. E.g.

[image]

I want the arrows to be right next to the letters, for example
[image]

Does anyone know which command I should use? Thanks!

Comment: You can always reduce the space: `\!`, etc.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! show us, how you obtain the first image of math expression in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surround `\downarrow` by `{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
$X{\downarrow}^G_H(h)=X(h)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\downarrow` is a relation symbol, putting it within `{...}` make it be treated as it belongs to the "ordinary" class.

As suggested by egreg, the same result can be achieved more elegantly using [`\mathord`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/mathord.htm):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\restr}{\mathord\downarrow} 
\newcommand{\ind}{\mathord\uparrow} 

\begin{document}
$X\restr^G_H(h)=X(h)$

and

$X\ind^G_H(h)=X(h)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes: `\downarrow` is a relation symbol. I think it would be better to define `\newcommand{\restr}{\mathord\downarrow}` and `\newcommand{\ind}{\mathord\uparrow}`